# How to optimize SQL without indexes

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, subquery

I have following query

```
SELECT *
FROM n
WHERE LOWER(n.info) LIKE '%searchparam%' ESCAPE '!'
    OR exists(
        SELECT 1
        FROM na
        WHERE n.id = na.n_id
          AND (LOWER(na.attribute_value) LIKE '%searchparam%' ESCAPE '!')
    )
    OR exists(
        SELECT 1
        FROM nr
        WHERE n.id = nr.n_id
          AND (LOWER(nr.address) LIKE '%searchparam%' ESCAPE '!')
    )
ORDER BY n.status_changed_date DESC;
```

There are 25 000 records in table **n**,
50 000 in **na**
and 26 000 in **nr**.

This query run in 7-8 seconds.

I want to know is it possible to optimize it without using index?

**Query Plan:**

```
Sort  (cost=6363642.74..6363690.30 rows=19022 width=476) (actual time=7350.659..7353.010 rows=14138 loops=1)
  Sort Key: n.status_changed_date DESC
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2464kB
  ->  Seq Scan on n (cost=0.00..6358192.22 rows=19022 width=476) (actual time=7213.903..7338.022 rows=14138 loops=1)
        Filter: ((alternatives: SubPlan 1 or hashed SubPlan 2) OR (lower(info) ~~ '%matter%'::text) OR (alternatives: SubPlan 3 or hashed SubPlan 4))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 11222
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Index Scan using ix_an_n_id on na  (cost=0.29..8.77 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)
                Index Cond: (n_id = n.id)
                Filter: (lower(attribute_value) ~~ '%matter%'::text)
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Seq Scan on na (cost=0.00..2355.80 rows=16 width=8) (actual time=31.707..6752.788 rows=17156 loops=1)
                Filter: (lower(attribute_value) ~~ '%matter%'::text)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 33564
        SubPlan 3
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on nr (cost=5.26..241.89 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)
                Recheck Cond: (n.id = n_id)
                Filter: (lower((address)::text) ~~ '%matter%'::text)
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_nr_n_id  (cost=0.00..5.26 rows=130 width=0) (never executed)
                      Index Cond: (n_id = n.id)
        SubPlan 4
          ->  Seq Scan on nr (cost=0.00..684.75 rows=8 width=8) (actual time=62.939..62.939 rows=0 loops=1)
                Filter: (lower((address)::text) ~~ '%matter%'::text)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 26050
Planning Time: 0.424 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 46
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 37.814 ms, Inlining 49.884 ms, Optimization 281.941 ms, Emission 163.050 ms, Total 532.689 ms"
Execution Time: 7394.066 ms
```

Comment: For every questions about optimization provide the actual, most detailed execution plan: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html

Comment: Without indexes, pretty hard... but there are options `SELECT n.* FROM n left join na on n.id = na.n_id left join nr on n.id = nr.n_id WHERE LOWER(n.info||'#'||na.attribute_value||'#'||nr.address) LIKE '%searchparam%' ESCAPE '!' ORDER BY n.status_changed_date DESC;` how does it perform? Another option is to use above tip with full text searches methods: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164081/42478

Comment: @JorgeCampos It performs very fast but gives wrong result.

Comment: why do you need to use LOWER keyword? Is your db case sensitive? using function in predicate columns could make performance problems.

Comment: @SerkanArslan The problem is that I dont know how to determine if my db is case sensitive or not. When I query it gives null collation_name. If i remove LOWER it gives wrong result

Comment: Instead of `lover(...) like ...` you can use `... ilike ...` (case insensitive `like`). It will be shorter at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting the query so that it uses UNION ALLs instead of ORs.

Check whether the database's collation is case sensitive or not.
If not, you don't need the lower.
If yes, you can try something like this
SELECT DISTINCT COL_NAME
FROM myTable
WHERE COL_NAME COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '%string%'

Get rid of the ORDER BY. You're reducing the engine's options to speed it up by having it.

If all that fails, see if you can get rid of the wildcards, especially the first one. Check this link out: https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimization-techniques-in-sql-server-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: + Order By can be quite time consuming if you don't need it (i.e. if your presentation layer will be doing sorting anyway)

Comment: @JeffUK I tried removing order by, but it did not help.

Comment: @Neve I tried removing LOWER and it actually helped, but I'm not sure about collation of the db, how do I check it?

Comment: Did you try using 'Union Alls'?

Comment: I tried using union all to unite 2 subqueries and it worked fast, but gave wrong result, I added distinct and it gave correct result but became slow.

Comment: You can go into the db and check what collation is set for the database and then try to find how that collation works with lower. But I'd personally just test it by hand to see what happens. I'm lazy... I'd try doing the union all and write into a temp table and then select distinct * from that temp table. What's killing you here is the wildcards, especially the first one. Can you take a look at this to see if you can use any of the options presented to eliminate the wildcard: https://www.sqlshack.com/query-optimization-techniques-in-sql-server-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM n
Left join na 
  on n.id = na.n_id
 AND LOWER(na.attribute_value)  LIKE '%searchparam%' ESCAPE '!'
Left join nr 
  on n.id = nr.n_id
 AND LOWER(nr.address) LIKE '%searchparam%' ESCAPE '!'
WHERE LOWER(n.info) LIKE '%searchparam%' ESCAPE '!' 
   OR coalesce(na.n_id, nr.n_id) is not null
ORDER BY n.status_changed_date DESC;
```

Use `distinct n.*` if it produces duplicate data.

Comment: Tried left join, it did not help a lot. I won 1 second.

Comment: Actually your indexes on info column will not help here as column is used against like with preceeding %